# Animate wobbling in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a wobble in swift, but with no luck so far. 
What I have is an egg on top of a table, and I want to bottom of the egg to kind of be stuck to the table, and the top of the egg to slowly wobble to the left and right.

I have tried this so far:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        completion?()
    })
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.autoreverses = true
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float( loops )
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = CGFloat(-0.1)
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(0.1)
    rotateAnimation.duration = 1.0
    animObject.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
```

However, this makes the entire egg rotate, including its bottom end, so it doesnt actually look like a wobble.

Picture you have a pencil in your hand, and you rotate it left and right. Both the top end of the pen and the bottom end go equally far out to the opposite sides of each other. Now put the bottom end of the pencil on a table, and tilt it left and right. Only the top end changes position.
Thats what Im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (might have to tweak slightly):

```
egg.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

This sets the anchor to the bottom middle, so now when you rotate, it will rotate around that point as opposed to `{0.5, 0.5}` which is the default.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It accomplishes what I want, but it also makes the imageview of the egg move about 50px up from where it actually is seated. I have to play around some to figure out that part. But great help :)